# Ошибка при установке модуля lxml

Tags: python, парсер, lxml, pip

При установке модуля lxml через  pip install столкнулся с проблемой. Модуль не ставится, при создании сборки появляется ошибка, и установка откатывается. Появляется cообщение вида:

Failed building wheel for lxml.

C:\Users\Evgeny\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitmokp7auq.c(1): fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: libxml/xpath.h: No such file or directory.

error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

ОС:W-10/

Answer (score 3):

Более комплексным решением, на мой взгляд, было бы установить дистрибутив [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/anaconda-overview), который решает данную и много потенциальных будущих проблем с установкой модулей, которые необходимо компилировать и других. Кроме того у Anaconda есть свой удобный менеджер управления пакетами (модулями) - [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

Помог пост: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511815/using-pip-to-install-modules-in-python-failing, а также хранилище бинарников для windows: 
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. Как ни странно, все встало так, как надо.